# Backbone.js frontend with RESTful Rails backend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, model-view-controller, frontend

I started in the web development world with PHP, and then Rails in the recent few years. Since then I've been doing all my web projects in Rails.

Recently there seems to be a movement towards making Rails as a pure RESTful backend service and using frontend framework such as Backbone.js for all frontend interaction. I'm wondering what's you guys' take on it? Will this be the eventual future?

As well, besides Backbone.js, what are some other alternatives for frontend framework for this purpose?

Also assuming that I will want to support both a desktop version and a mobile version of my app, would this be a proper route to take? So I'll have a single backend service with different frontend services? This way I don't need to manage all the views on Rails' side?

Thanks!

Comment: Check these out if you haven't already, http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1 and http://railscasts.com/episodes/325-backbone-on-rails-part-2 helped me understand bootstrap a lot better.  Def start to see the usefulness of such a framework.  Ryan put all his rails routes in an api namespace to seperate it from the webapp part, that seems intuitive to me also.

Comment: uuummmm, backbone, not bootstrap... :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For Client-side frameworks, this article has a list of 20 of them with pro's and con's:
http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/20-javascript-frameworks-worth-checking-out/

Here's the list:

1. [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)
2. [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/)
3. [Asana luna](http://asana.com/luna/)
4. [Cappucino](http://cappuccino.org/)
5. [Sproutcore](http://sproutcore.com/)
6. [BatmanJS](http://batmanjs.org/)
7. [corMVC](http://www.bennadel.com/projects/cormvc-jquery-framework.htm)
8. [TrimJunction](http://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/TrimJunction)
9. [pureMVC](http://puremvc.org/)
10. [jamal](https://github.com/adcloud/jamal)
11. [choco](https://github.com/ahe/choco)
12. [sammyjs](http://sammyjs.org/)
13. [extJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)
14. [agilityJS](http://agilityjs.com/)
15. [eyeballs](https://github.com/paulca/eyeballs.js)
16. [activejs](http://www.activejs.org/)
17. [spinejs](http://spinejs.com/)
18. [qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/)

These are roughly all about creating client-side, ajax-based, javascript MVC frameworks.

If you're looking to start somewhere, then I recommend thinking about **Client-Side Templates** (...ates...ates...ates) (just the "V") to support a service-oriented architecture (many clients are supported by service-endpoints you create).

It's a new technique that involves modularizing your client-side code, bringing MVC to the client, and let business-logic live in the platform. A lot of Software-as-a-Service applications are leveraging them, and with the increasing sophisticated of javascript libraries and frameworks, as well as browser capabilities with HTML5, CSS3, etc. there's going to be an increasing sophistication in client-side presentation.

So learn it.

What are the benefits?

To paraphrase Linked In: for leveraging browser-caching, de-coupling your front-end client-side presentation, asynchronous load, progressive rendering (for some frameworks), performance, ajax-interaction, and more.

Several great frameworks include:

1. [mustache](http://mustache.github.com/)
2. [dust.js](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/)
3. [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
4. [Google Closure Templates](http://code.google.com/closure/templates/)
5. [Nun](https://github.com/akaspin/nun)
6. [Mu](https://github.com/raycmorgan/Mu)
7. [kite](http://code.google.com/p/kite/)

I highly recommend looking at [Linked In's move away from JSP towards Client-Side Templates](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/leaving-jsps-dust-moving-linkedin-dustjs-client-side-templates) and why they choose dust.js in [Linked In's front-end client-side templates throwdown](http://engineering.linkedin.com/frontend/client-side-templating-throwdown-mustache-handlebars-dustjs-and-more) for a comparison. They go into much greater detail, and research, as to why they changed their stack to support this (it involved using 3 server-side technologies), as well as their comparisons of all the frameworks they could find.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just read the two linkedin articles that you have provided. I think I'm beginning to understand the client-side templates scene a bit better. However, a question once again lingers, so what's really the differences between this and some MVC framework like backbone.js? This sounds like what I would like to have, but when I heard about backbone.js with Rails, it also sounded like what I was talking about. What are the differences between them? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "this" and "some MVC framework" like backbone.js? Each of these frameworks basically ARE MVC frameworks that leverage ajax (and other technologies) to interact with the services / server-side application. They just have their pro's and cons. backbone is just a really popular one that follows ajax + models heavily.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought backjone.js was something that was different from the ones that you have listed. Since it wasn't in your list of frameworks and linkedin's.  I guess I had wrongfully assumed that you guys thought backbone.js shoudld've been an option too haha. Thanks!

Comment: Well it's a really good question, and I hope I haven't steered you wrong with client-side templates. Backbone.js just takes it a step further by providing "Client-side MVC". It assists with the serialization (which the suggested ones above also do) as well as the display (like the others) but has some excellent features in leveraging the MODEL. That's where Backbone shines: in mapping to your server-side model, it will make representing changes in state and interaction from user gestures so much easier to replicate on any client. I'd recommend delving into it.

Comment: Thanks for the new answer. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this a few years ago in .net. Is was not via proper .NET MVC and didn't use the new JS frameworks, but the principle was the same; server code returns JSON to javascript which builds the page and interactions etc.

The result was a lovely responsive website, but, maintenance was a nightmare. Be very careful to keep your JS code well organised.

Personally, I find it easier to maintain server code (in any language) than javascript so I wouldn't go down that route again.

(IMHO)

Fran

Answer (score 2):

It is my opinion that contemporary web applications are moving towards this model of having RESTful back-end and all the view interactions coded in front-end. These free video tutorials from Joe Zim:

http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/introduction-to-backbone-js-part-1-models-video-tutorial/

helped me understand backbone and how it can simplify templating and view renders.